# Remove null from textfield and textarea using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a database table where some column have null value

I'm saving the value using formData

like

```
formData.append('remark', this.form.remark);
```

but when i retrieve the data in field i get null in my textfield.

```
 <textarea v-model="form.remark" class="form-control"> </textarea>

  mounted(){ 
                  
          const header = {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.getLoginUserData,
          }
         this.editId = this.$route.params.id;
         axios.get(`/api/backend/userdata/${this.editId}` , {headers : header})
         .then((response) => {   
            this.form = response.data;
```

form initialization :

```
form: {
                name: '',
                remark: '',
```

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you try to retrieve the data and where?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: in the mounted part i'm fetching all data i have updated my code above please check

Comment: How is `form` initialized?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: form is initialized like `form: {   name: '',  designation: ''}` like this

Comment: it should be initialized using the field like `form: {   name: '',  designation: '',remark:''}`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: remark in also there but if blank then in my database null is stored and on edit the same null is shown in field

Comment: what do you see in the `response.data`?

Comment: @Naren: `remark: "null"` I'm getting this value in response.data.remark

Comment: then just add check before assigning the data.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, It could be small issue with your data. `null` is coming as string so you just need to add a small check before adding data to the form.

Try like this.

```
Object.keys(response.data).forEach(key => {
   if (response.data[key] && response.data[key] !== 'null') {
       this.form[key] = response.data[key]
   }
})
```

**Note**: This will add all the properties of `response.data` to the form.